# Excel show index value from a string separated by commas by specific character

Tags: excel, list, indexing, extract

I´ve been looking for a way to do this all day, but no luck.

So I have a table with one column "Body Style" and each cell has a string of numbers separated by comma, each item of the list or string can be something like "1234,1259131819,1213451817", the size of the list is always variable so in some cells a list can have 40 sets of numbers separated by commas. I want to identify each set of numbers that contains the number "18" if the list item is "13171819" that one counts as it contains the 18.
At the end I need to obtain a list with the index value for each set of number that contains the "18".
Example:
input="59121213,1112131819,59,121318"
output="2,4" if the index starts with 1 and not with 0, otherwise it would be "1,3"

Once I have the string with the index values that matches the "18" I need to extract from the Qty column the values that correspond to that index as they are related. In simple words I want to know only the qty values for the index values that contain an "18".

Hope my explanation was clear, and someone can help me to do this.

[image]

Example:
input="59121213,1112131819,59,121318"
output="2,4" if the index starts with 1 and not with 0, otherwise it would be "1,3"

Once I have the string with the index values that matches the "18" I need to extract from the Qty column the values that correspond to that index as they are related. In simple words I want to know only the qty values for the index values that contain an "18".

Answer (score 0):

To get index number try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(SEQUENCE(1,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))+1),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("18",TEXTSPLIT(B1,",")&""))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a Function which takes two parameters: a) the field to be searched and  b) the value you are looking for. RETURNS the indexes of the subfields... zero based:

```
Public Function getIndexes(str As String, lookfor As String)
   Dim s() As String, c As Integer, cfrom As Integer, cto As Integer, sep As String
   s = Split(str, ",")
   sep = ""
   cfrom = LBound(s)
   cto = UBound(s)
   For c = cfrom To cto
      If InStr(1, s(c), lookfor) > 0 Then
         getIndexes = getIndexes & sep & c
         sep = ","
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

If cell A1 = "112233, 113344, 225566" and cell A2 = "22" then if in cell
A3 write: =getIndexes(A1,A2) will get  0,2